# Quotation marks or italics when quoting the title of a painting ("The plaque read...")

Tags: style-manuals, italics

After much research, I'm stumped. Do I use quotes or italics for the last word in the following sentence?

> There's a painting of a yacht with a gold plate on the lower frame that reads Facets.

As the painting title, it should be in italics; however, since it's quoting what the plate says, maybe quotation marks are better?

Also, if using italics, should there be a comma after "reads?"

Comment: Italics aren't punctuation. Quotes are. Hope that helps. (Regarding the comma, I'd say it's not required.)

Comment: Thanks, Tushar Raj.  My question is, do I use italics or quotation marks on the last word?  I updated my question in case that was unclear.

Comment: I think you should use quotes. Consider the plaque said something else. Wouldn't you write: The plaque below _Facets_ reads "amazeballs". I can't say I'm sure about this, though. This is just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/about16_rules.html):

> Titles of photographs are now treated like those of paintings—that is, set in italics. 8.193.

As for whether a comma is needed, I don't think so.  See [Is a Comma Needed to Offset a Title](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107257/is-a-comma-needed-to-offset-a-title) for more info.